# how to display only date part of date time properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor-pages

My field of table in sql is in date format and the field property in asp core is datetime.
I use javascript to show data in table but I it shows datetime in table how can I just show date.
script to bring data in table:

```
 function LoadTable(Data) {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++) {
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].Id + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].PersonName + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].BirthDate + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].IssueDate + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>'
        }
        $('#tbl_Data tbody').html(html);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
function LoadTable(Data) {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++) {
            const birthDate = ( new Date( Data[i].BirthDate ).getMonth()+1 ) + '-' + new Date( Data[i].BirthDate ).getDate() + '-' + new Date( Data[i].BirthDate ).getFullYear();
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].Id + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].PersonName + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + birthDate + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + Data[i].IssueDate + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>'
        }
        $('#tbl_Data tbody').html(html);
    }
```